# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with fixed delay?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Job which is scheduled to run every hour which uses Spring `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean to fire simultaneous calls (close to 100 calls every hour) to external API.

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor getExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

Now, the external API has throttled the number of requests and allows one request per 30 secs. I will have to wait 30 secs before making each call.

In this case, I see use of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is no longer helpful. Will `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with Fixed Delay configuration work?

What is the best way to handle such type of API throttling? Please help

I'm on Java 8, Spring Boot 2.0.1 if that helps

Comment: You are actually aware of the solution, a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ` scheduler with a 30 seconds delayed trigger would work. Why wouldn't you just implement that? Are there any reasons?

Comment: @tmarwen I have used `@Scheduled` with a cron expression in the actual Job which runs every hour. Can I have a concurrent fixed delay schedule in ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ?

Comment: @jusemar10 You might like to control the schedule on your @Scheduled annotation and leave the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` alone.

Comment: I assume what you actually need is some kind of way to spread out the calls so it knows how much time has passed since the last one, and puts them on the queue if tasks need throttling. Although none of this helps if you don't change your app in a meaningfull way: you have to change it so it goes from 100 calls a minute to at most 2 calls. This isn't achievable with just throttling the executor.

Comment: ... because if you just change the executor, and still load it with 100 tasks while it can process 2 at most, the tasks queue would get polluted very fast (98 a minute at least, to be precise).

Comment: @m-prokhorov Probably a queue would work in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

1. Configure the `TaskExecutor`. You have already done this.
2. Write a method that you want to invoke in a scheduled fashion and annotate with `@Scheduled`.

   ```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3600000)
    void doSomething() {
    }
   ```

The code above will trigger every 1 hour.

Comment: I have this setup already. My question is how to limit the API call which is currently fired about 100 times in parallel every time the job runs.

Comment: This will always throttle the task, even if there were no tasks run for the past 10 minutes.

Comment: Agree with @M.Prokhorov . Your problem is not in the domain of the Scheduling infrastructure that Spring provides. You would probably have to build your own logic. Maybe your own custom logic (or reuse lower level of task management infrastructure from Java itself or Spring) to submit tasks to an intermediate processor. That intermediate processor would keep track of timestamps, and would coordinate a proper delay between consecutive submissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I'll try and provide an answer anyway for anyone else who may be facing a similar issue.

1. Continue to use `TaskExecutor` to launch every hour.
2. Use a `RateLimiter` function in WebClient to limit the calls to the
   external service, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075755/16490192) for a fine example.