# Rate limit web client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am building a microservice using spring webflux and netty. Internally I use web client to make rest api calls. How can I control rate at which I can call rest api via webclient? I guess backnpressure is only for a single request/reply and does not work across multiple request to my microservice. Amy pointers will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the request/second with WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387584/how-to-limit-the-request-second-with-webclient)

Answer (score 1):

Resilience4j has support for **non-blocking** rate limiting with Reactor.
See: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-1#decorate-mono-or-flux-with-a-ratelimiter